# Why would Google Maps Directions avoids a public walking path?

Tags: google-maps

My goal is to draw a walking route on Google Maps. There is a path that is clearly the shortest, but Google Maps avoids it, even if it is a public road.

Why does Google avoid it ?

[Here is the directions](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/50.6323397,4.643783/50.6260044,4.642747/@50.6285222,4.6435889,17.17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2), if you zoom in near the pond you'll see a route "Chemin aux Fraises" that
Google avoids.

Comment: The road that Chemin aux Fraises terminates at isn't labeled and seems to solely serve  the farm it surrounds terminating at some farm buildings.  I imagine that the path Chemin aux  Fraises became a link between that road and Rue Aux Fraises as a matter of convenience.  If the unlabeled road is essentially a private driveway, albeit a very long one, that may explain it.  Just spit-balling

Comment: There is no road sign indicating that those roads are forbidden. Afaik they all are public, I often go there. There is just one part of _Rue aux Fraises_ that Google labels as a restricted-usage road (see comment below).

Answer (score 0):

The road/path you mention is restricted. You can drag a blue circle onto the road to change the path, but you'll see the below side-bar. You'd need to ask Google to remove this restriction, to allow Maps to use it as a valid route.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. This route "Rue aux Fraises" is labelled as a restricted-usage road on your directions. But when I go for _Edit the map_ > _Add or fix a road_, the "Private road" checkbox is unchecked. So, if it is a public road, why is it restricted ?

Comment: Best to contact Google, then.